# How to get full access to the variable in another Unity class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am beginer and i am making "Score Funtion" in my ball game. I code like this:

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour {
Playerturn playerturn;    //Playerturn is another class


private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "ground")
    {
        // if (stopped == true)
        Destroy(gameObject);
        playerturn.player1score++;    
    }
  }
}
```

But player1score in Playerturn class has never been changed any ways. I tried many differents way to fix but it 's not work. So is there some way to access to player1score of Playerturn class and change that variable.

Answer (score 0):

`OnCollisionExit` is a public function, not private.
try it like this:

```
public void OnCollisionExit....
```

thanks.